# How to get Card id on event calling in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

My code has a const given below -

```
 const cardObject=[
        
        {
                "img":"/my_web_resume/static/media/tcs.cab517d9.jpg",
                "title":"Tata Consultancy Services",
                "des":"Currrently working with TCS as a System Engineer",
                "period":"Jan 2020 - Present",
                "loc":"Noida, UttarPradesh"
        
            },
            {
        
                "img":"/my_web_resume/static/media/mapmyindia.67305014.jpg",
                "title":"MapMyIndia",
                "des":"Worked With MapmyIndia as a Software Development Engineer",
                "period":"Mar 2018 - Jan 2019",
                "location":"Noida, UttarPradesh"
        
            }
        ]
```

this one is passed as a prop to the another component -

```
  <Experience crdObj={cardObject} onClick={this.handleClick} />
```

I also pass a call back function to Experience component.

Here I created 2 cards like this -

```
class Experience extends Component{
     render() {
 return (
          <div className={`container  mt-2 w-100 ${styles.container}`} >
        {/* <MyCard className={styles.mycard} src={tcsimg} title="Tata Consultancy Services" text="Currently working with TCS as a System Engineer." date="From Jan 2020 To Present" location="Location - Noida,UP"/>
        <MyCard classname={styles.mycard} src={mmimg} title="MapMyIndia" text="Worked with MapMyIndia as a Software Development Engineer." date="From Mar 2018 To Jan 2019" location="Location - Okhla,Delhi"/> */}
{
  this.props.crdObj.map(item=>
  {
    

return <MyCard className={styles.mycard} src={item.img} title={item.title} text={item.des} date={item.period} location={item.loc} onClick={this.props.onClick} />


  })
}
 </div>
        )
   }
    }
```

Now I pass all parameters to card component-

```
class MyCard extends Component

{ render() {
     
 return (
            <div >
            <Card style={{ width: '18rem' }} className={styles.card}>
    <Card.Img variant="top" src={this.props.src} className={styles.img} />

    <Card.Body>
        <Card.Title>{this.props.title}</Card.Title>
      <Card.Text>
       {this.props.text}
      </Card.Text>
    </Card.Body>
    <ListGroup className="list-group-flush">
        <ListGroupItem>{this.props.date}</ListGroupItem>
        <ListGroupItem>{this.props.location}</ListGroupItem>
      {/* <ListGroupItem>Vestibulum at eros</ListGroupItem> */}
    </ListGroup>
    <Card.Body>
      {console.log(this.props.onClick)}
      <Card.Link onClick={this.props.onClick}>know more..</Card.Link>
      {/* <Card.Link href="#">Another Link</Card.Link> */}
    </Card.Body>
  </Card>
        
       </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Here the card component calls function which I passed as a prop.The function calls perfectly but when I clicked on know more..how do I know which card is clicked.I want to pass the card parameters to the parent.

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pass an onClick function form parent to child like this

```
return <MyCard cardObject={cardobject} handleClick={this.handleCardClick} />
```

define your handleClick function in Parent component

```
const handleCardClick = (cardObject) => {
    console.log( "clicked card is " , cardObject);
}
```

then call the onClick function inside child component

```
<div onClick={ () => this.props.handleClick(this.props.cardobject)} >

 <Card>

</Card>

</div>
```

Comment: MyCard.js:30 Uncaught TypeError: this.props.onClick is not a function
    at onClick (MyCard.js:30)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:188)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:237)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:292)
    at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError .

Comment: can you check my edited answer and let me know if it works ?

Answer (score 0):

```
 this.props.crdObj.map((item, key)=>
  {
    return <MyCard 
    className={styles.mycard}
    src={item.img}
    title={item.title} 
    text={item.des}
    date={item.period}
    location={item.loc}
    id={key}
    onClick={this.props.onClick}
/>
})
}
```

Comment: how do I access it in parent class?